# Route match to dynamic actions in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

**Can I write one row route for below two rows?**

```
match "/article/:id/"  => "articles#redirect"
match "/articles/:id/" => "articles#redirect"
```

I tried something like

```
  match "/:article_redirect/:id/" => "articles#redirect", :constraints => {:article_redirect => /[article|articles]/}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: my suggestion is to get rid of match as this is obsolete in rails4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your regexp id not good: try

```rb
match "/:article_redirect/:id/" => "articles#redirect", :constraints => {:article_redirect => /(article|articles)/}
```

that is `(article|articles)` instead of `[article|articles]`

Comment: Sorry, I deleted by error a `{` after `constraints`; corrected.